# Android Studio automatically execute the breakpoint after 10 secs?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, breakpoints

In Android Studio is there any option like breakpoint such that I can resume the breakpoint automatically after some time(for e.g- 10 secs).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this approach is working for me, when I need to call any API or any background task after 10 secs, then I just put the breakpoint only in the background thread code, e.g- doInbackground() Or in retrofit interceptors. Because as previously I was using breakpoints in the UI thread code, that's why whole app was freezing and none of my UI thread methods were getting called, but now my UI thread is doing all the tasks normally, it's just the background that that has been paused now after 10 secs I manually resume this breakpoint.

Currently, this approach only works if I want any background operation to call afetr some time without any impact on UI thread code, also As I am manually calling resume after 10 secs don't know how to do it automatically.